# CTest add tests in subdirectories

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a CMake-based project that consists of several sub-components, which can all be independently compiled and tested. The directory layout looks like this:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── comp1
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── foo.cc
│   │   └── foo.h
│   └── tests
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── test_comp1.cc
└── comp2
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── src
    │   ├── bar.cc
    │   └── bar.h
    └── tests
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── test_comp2.cc
```

I want to enable ctest, therefore in the root CMakeLists.txt I have `include(CTest)` and in the component-specific CMakeLists.txt files I have

```
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

In compX/tests/CMakeLists.txt I have the code to compile the test and the `add_test()`command. The tests get successfully compiled and I can manually run them. However, if I call `ctest`, it returns

```
No tests were found!!!
```

After playing a bit with this, it turned out that if I move the `add_subdirectory(tests)` call to the root CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  add_subdirectory(comp1/tests)
endif()
```

it works. But I find this quite ugly and messy, to put component-specific stuff into the root file.

Conversely, I tried to move the `include(CTest)` command one level down into the component-specific CMakeLists.txt. But `ctest` complains with this:

```
*********************************
No test configuration file found!
*********************************
```

Is there seriously no way to use ctest with a directory structure like above?

Comment: It could be that `comp1/CMakeLists.txt` disables `BUILD_TESTING` option, or replace `add_test` command. Note, that if your call `include(CTest)` in the *subdirectory*, `ctest` should be executed in the subdirectory too; it won't work from the top-level directory.

Comment: How do you mean "replace `add_test`"?

Comment: A standard CMake command can be replaced with user-provided function or macro with the same name. E.g. one may define `function(add_test)`. Anywhere, we could only *guess* what is wrong with your `tests/CMakeLists.txt` - you didn't show it in the question post.

Comment: Did you try to run them using `cmake --build build --target test` (UNIX) ?, otherwise ctest must be run from the binary directory where `enable_testing()` has been call (which is done internally by the macro `include(CTest)`)
src: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CTest.cmake#L84

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The CTest documentation isn't the clearest.

A project I'm working on has a similar directory structure composed of various units, and in each unit are src and tests subdirectories.

CMake documentation says to call "enable_testing()" at the top-level CMakeLists.txt file, and it further says this command will "enable CTest at the current directory and below." Which sounds recursive, right? Well it's not.

Every CMakeLists.txt must have enable_testing() called to enable automatic CTest discovery in that directory.

Thus, in your project, the toplevel CMakeLists.txt will need enable_testing(), then comp{1,2}/CMakeLists.txt will need it, and finally comp{1,2}/tests/CMakeLists.txt will need it.

Once you add those commands and rerun cmake, those directories will each contain a CTestTestfile.cmake file, which is what the ctest program will look for when it runs.

Comment: Actually it is recursive. You just have to make sure to call `enable_testing()` before `add_subdirectory`. `enable_testing()` documentation states that `This command should be in the source directory root because ctest expects to find a test file in the build directory root.` You just have to make sure this is done before any `add_subdirectory` calls.